# Difficulty with while loop in Python fractal drawing program

Tags: python, while-loop, draw, turtle-graphics, fractals

I´m having a problem with `while` in my code:

```
import turtle
import random

print('ENTRADA: F-F-F-F')
print('REGRA: F F-F+F+FF-F-F+F ')

pen = turtle.Pen()

inicial = input("Entrada: ")
regra =input("regra: ")
passos=int(input("passos: "))

final=""
regra = regra.split(' ')


i=0
while i < passos:
    final = inicial.replace(regra[i],regra[i+1] )
i+=1


print(final)
```

Python error code:

```
    final = inicial.replace(regra[i],regra[i+1] )

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to do. Please specify your question! The indentation of `i+=1`is in my opinion wrong. Also change the input variables to the adequate type, example: `inicial = str(input("Entry:"))`

Comment: Please use English in your code on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is closer to what you desire:

```
print('Example:')
print('Input: F-F-F-F')
print('Rule: F F-F+F+FF-F-F+F')
print()

initial = input("Input: ")
rule = input("Rule: ")
steps = int(input("Steps: "))

final = initial
old, new = rule.split(maxsplit=1)

for _ in range(steps):
    final = final.replace(old, new)

print(final)
```